# I can't get chromium's android source code

Tags: android, chromium

I followed the instructions of android chromium homepage - [Android build instructions](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/docs/android_build_instructions.md) , but I found the genarate tool output a lot of source code. Is there a way to get only the android source code?

I want to get only the android chromium source code.

Comment: What do you actually mean when you say "I want to get only android chromium source" ?

Comment: Chromium shares a lot of cross platform code. So you can't just get code for Android only. For example, the Android source code has so many C++ libraries which are used for Android, Mac, Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the instructions, you **have** got the android chromium source code. If you expected java/kotlin sourcecode for an activity or few, you're out of luck.

Comment: means there is no way to get a normal android project right? so is there any tutorial to customize it?

Comment: It is a normal android project, it's just not an android app written in Java/kotlin that uses only Android SDK.